# Is having precalculated fields on the database to avoid deep join queries a bad idea?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, data-modeling

I have this data model in my application (Django/Rest Framewrok). It mainly lists and operates with **Project** and **Release** classes, which has several instances per system affected and multiple phases per instance which have different efforts.

I am developing a RESTful API for a frontend, and I'm having trouble with load times when listing all the **Projects** for a **Release**, or all the active **Projects**. I need to go down to the **ProjectInstancePhase** to get the overall effort for Project o Release elements.

Would having precalculated values on the Project or Release objects that update when an dependent object is updated be a bad idea? I know it breaks the normalization of the database, but it would save a lot of time. Think about listing 300 projects with all the related data.

I've thought about caching, but I would need to invalidate it often because any change in the related classes would need to be shown.

Is threre some ORM trick to lower the load on the database?

All the tutorials and examples usually rely on simple data models that seldom reflect real life complex projects so I haven't find this topic covered on them.

Thanks a lot.

```
                                       *Listed               *Listed
+--------+       +------------+      +-----------+         +----------+
| Person +>-----<+ Participant+>----<+  Project  +>-------<+ Release  |
+--------+       +------------+      +-----------+         +----------+
                                          v
                                          ^
                 +--------+      +-----------------+
                 | System +>----<+ ProjectInstance |
                 +--------+      +-----------------+
                                          v
                                          ^
                               +----------------------+        +--------------+
                               | ProjectInstancePhase +>------<+ ProjectPhase |
                               +----------------------+        +--------------+
                                       *Effort
```

Comment: Denormalisation is a perfectly valid technique, as long as it's used sparingly and for the right reasons. The tricky part is making sure the values stay in sync.

Comment: Yes, I've developed a Mixin to check for changes on selected fields before saving, so I can update the related fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using such approach pretty often. You can use Django's signals to update precalculated fields (or even precalculated instances of some dedicated model).

Also, you even can perform some updates only in specific cases (for example, field `a` changed it value from positive number to negative etc. — in overridden `.save()` method there is possibility to have access to all instance fields values before update and to compare them with values after update.

Let me know if you need examples.

Comment: Thank you. I will use that approach, but with a Mixin to check specific fields change. I also have to take a look to query optimization using prefetch_related and select_related for when I need to select the whole tree for some models.